# Is there any way to see numbers for weapon upgrades in Saints Row: The Third?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

Saints Row: The Third has introduced an upgrade system for the weapons. Paying extra cash allows you to upgrade to various levels (I've so far seen 4; I don't know if there's more), but it only has descriptions for its upgrades rather than numbers.

For example, in order to upgrade my 45 Shepherd to Level 3, I'd need to pay $10,000. The description says `Increase the size of your clips` but it doesn't say by how much. Without knowing the numbers, I'm not sure whether or not I want to upgrade my weapon or simply buy a new one with better base stats.

Is there any way to see actual numbers for the upgrades, either in the game itself or perhaps on a wiki or website somewhere? I'm playing the Xbox 360 version, so I lack the ability to install any mods or check any files for myself.

Comment: The [Saints Row wiki](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Weapons_in_Saints_Row:_The_Third) does not have stats for weapons, just the upgrade costs and descriptions that we see in the game. That's disappointing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Saints Row: The Third* is basically an almost statless game from the player's perspective. For the most part, all you know about most upgrades is that it will provide "more" of "something" (even if it says +25% more, the base number is unkown). Just go for it, the money is going to come rolling in anyways so you will always have an opportunity to buy a different upgrade.